# Dual OS onHDD. Standard Linux boot hangs. Safe boot option to retry standard loads fine. what's up?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

New install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from disk from Linux User magazine.  Standard boot hangs. Safe boot displays option to retry standard boot and when selected loads fine. Have updated OS. Any suggestions to get standard boot to work? Ubuntu is on disk along with Windows XP. Thanks....

Comment: Please post the output of [bootinfo script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) to help us analyse the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First does windows boot properly?
If it does then maybe the Grub boot loader just made a mistake somewhere. 
With what little information you suppled thats the only thing I can think of.
You can try this, as sometimes it repairs a Grub error.

While Ubuntu is running open the terminal, Type sudo update-initramfs -u

Enter your password when ask for it (don't worry that you do not see any "*'s " just type it)

Let it finish then type sudo update-grub

Enter your password if ask for it

let it finish then close terminal and reboot.